# APC FOR PHP 5.3.8

Tags: php, apc, acceleration

I've been trying to install apc . I've added the .dll file to the extenstions directory ( so far i'm running the application on xamppm, apache) . I've also updated the php.ini as well.
The problem comes up when I restart the apache and then the next warning appears :

```
php startup : unable to load dynamic library c:/xampp/php/ext/php_apc.dll
```

I think the problem might be the fact that the php version I employ is 5.3.8 .
I've been looking for apc download for php 5.3.8 and I hadn't found any,

What am I able to do in order to solve this problem ?

Any suggestion will be helpful , thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was because i was using x64 version of WAMP server so i downloaded the x64 version of php_apc.dll file and it worked.
Here is a [link](http://www.mediafire.com/php-win64-extensions)

Answer (score 0):

In the following site you'll be able to find the extension compiled for Windows in a variety of "flavours" ready to download:

http://dev.freshsite.pl/php-accelerators/apc.html

Hint: you mention you use XAMPP, which as far as I can tell bundles PHP compiled with VC9 and thread safe, so you are probably looking for [this one](http://dev.freshsite.pl/php-accelerators/apc/file/details/apc-319-for-php-53-vc9-win72008.html) if you use Windows 7 or [this one](http://dev.freshsite.pl/php-accelerators/apc/file/details/apc-319-for-php-53-vc9.html) for other windows versions.

Side note: As somebody who has been using Apache and PHP under win heavily, I can only recommend to switch to Linux as soon as you can: PHP extensions (among many other things) are way much less of a headache there.